# New error message: when= parameter of the strategy entry function will be removed in the future version is not applicable to respective code

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Pinescript has started showing error messages saying that the when= parameter of the strategy entry function would be removed in the future version of Pine Script (current version 5 won't be affected).
TV support stated that if one would like to preserve the compatibility with future versions, instead of the when= parameter condition, a local "if" or "switch" block should be used.  As an example, TV recommends changing this line of code:
`strategy.entry("LongEntryId", strategy.long, when = longCondition)`
to:
`if (longCondition) strategy.entry("LongEntryId", strategy.long)`

However, my code the error message refers to doesn't use the "when" parameter:

```
    alertno := 31
    switch
        (Position == 3 and close > long_target_entry) => 
            strategy.close('golong', comment="T1", qty_percent = 33)
            Performance := (close - Tradeprice) / Tradeprice * 100
```

The stratey.entry line also doesn't use the "when" parameter.
How can I change my code so that the error message doesn't reappear? Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: This is known bug. Fix is in progress ...

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your friendly hint, problem indeed seems to be solved now